# How properly wrap async http requests into success and fail callbacks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, request, void

I'm refactoring old code which does synchronous http requests and returns Callback object with success and fail events. How to properly wrap code into async/await?

I've added HttpClient class and I'm using SendAsync method on which I await, but I'm not sure how properly make transition from await into events. I've added async void Execute method in class but it does not seem like correct way of handling - avoid async void. Below more explanation in (short version of) code.

```
public class HttpExecutor(){

    public event Action<string> Succeed;
    public event Action<ErrorType, string> Failed;
    private bool isExecuting;

    //I know that async void is not the best because of exceptions
    //and code smell when it is not event handler
    public async void Execute()
        {
            if (isExecuting) return;

            isExecuting = true;
            cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            try
            {
                httpResponseMessage =
                    await httpService.SendAsync(requestData, cancellationTokenSource.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);

                var responseString = string.Empty;
                if (httpResponseMessage.Content != null)
                {
                    responseString = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }

                if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Succeed?.Invoke(responseString);
                    return;
                }

                Failed?.Invoke(httpResponseMessage.GetErrorType(),
                    $"{httpResponseMessage.ReasonPhrase}\n{responseString}");
            }
            //Catch all exceptions separately
            catch(...){
            }
            finally
            {
                Dispose();
            }
        }
}

public class UserService(){

    public CallbackObject<User> GetUser(){
        var executor = new HttpExecutor(new RequestData());
        //CallbackObject has also success and fail, and it hooks to executor events, deserializes string into object and sends model by his own events.
        var callback = new CallbackObject<User>(executor);
        executor.Execute();//in normal case called when all code has possibility to hook into event
        return callback;
    }

}
```

I feel that I should change method to:`public async Task ExecuteAsync(){...}` but then I would need take thread from thread pool by doing: `Task.Run(()=>executor.ExecuteAsync());`

It seems like it's a bit of fire and forget, but with callbacks (I await for response from network). How to handle this properly?

Comment: Why would you want to go back to callbacks after experiencing the awesomeness of async/await? :-).

Comment: Is there any reason you need the actions? was the original use case to free up the UI for responsiveness?

Comment: "but then I would need take thread from thread pool" - why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm refactoring old code which does synchronous http requests and returns Callback object with success and fail events. How to properly wrap code into async/await?

You get rid of the callbacks completely.

First, consider the failure case. `(ErrorType, string)` should be made into a custom `Exception`:

```
public sealed class ErrorTypeException : Exception
{
  public ErrorType ErrorType { get; set; }

  ...
}
```

Then you can model `Succeed` / `Failed` callbacks as a single `Task<string>`:

```
public async Task<string> ExecuteAsync()
{
  if (isExecuting) return;
  isExecuting = true;

  cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  try
  {
    httpResponseMessage = await httpService.SendAsync(requestData, cancellationTokenSource.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var responseString = string.Empty;
    if (httpResponseMessage.Content != null)
    {
      responseString = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      return responseString;

    throw new ErrorTypeException(httpResponseMessage.GetErrorType(),
        $"{httpResponseMessage.ReasonPhrase}\n{responseString}");
  }
  catch(...){
    throw ...
  }
  finally
  {
    Dispose();
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
public Task<User> GetUserAsync()
{
  var executor = new HttpExecutor(new RequestData());
  var text = await executor.ExecuteAsync();
  return ParseUser(text);
}
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, thank you very much for fast reply and help! I think that your answer satisfies me, but I just need one clarification. I will try to explain my best. Since now whenever I want to call GetUserAsync(), the best way would be to refactor caller of GetUserAsync() to be await/async - spreads like a virus :). When does it stop, or how to start this whole async flow of calls? At this point I'm not sure if I will be able to refactor all methods to async await. Should I just start with Task.Run(()=> GetUserAsync())?Ps.I've got your book, but recently don't have much time to read it ;(

Comment: @AAGames: The best approach is to let it grow; the name of this principle is ["async all the way"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). If you need to do a partial translation, you could look into writing an executor-like wrapper around `Task<T>`, so part of your code could still use events. Temporarily, of course - you don't want to keep two different asynchronous patterns for very long.